# On Android Virtual Device, all applications are stopping on launch

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I know that this question was probably asked, yet I couldn't find a case matches to mine after some searching.

I've made it to show my first app on the AVD by adding

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

to the manifest, something that google's tutorial was not telling you to do directly ([shame on you, google](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#Emulator))

yet now, on running the application, the AVD alerts that "Test App has stopped".

Now the thing is, the AVD alerted that it could follow up on the errors(?), I just gave it to it's job. the error list is long, so I won't paste it, but I would like if you could check the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
```

sorry for the trouble, and thanks.
a little edit: I did google research, but came up with nothing to match those errors.

Due to request, Following Errors:

> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): Process:
>   com.example.testapp, PID: 1400
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.Main}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.testapp.Main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.testapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-2, /system/lib]]
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.testapp.Main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.testapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-2, /system/lib]]
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>
> 03-17 16:40:59.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1400):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423): Process:
>   com.example.testapp, PID: 1423
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.Main}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.testapp.Main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.testapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-2, /system/lib]]
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.testapp.Main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.testapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-2, /system/lib]]
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>
> 03-17 16:49:13.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1423):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446): Process:
>   com.example.testapp, PID: 1446
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.Main}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.testapp.Main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.testapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-2, /system/lib]]
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.testapp.Main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.testapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-2, /system/lib]]
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>
> 03-17 16:49:32.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1446):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580): Process:
>   com.example.testapp, PID: 1580
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.testapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.testapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-2, /system/lib]]
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.testapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.testapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-2, /system/lib]]
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>
> 03-17 16:53:30.202: E/AndroidRuntime(1580):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721): Process:
>   com.example.testapp, PID: 1721
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.testapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.testapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-2, /system/lib]]
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.testapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.testapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testapp-2, /system/lib]]
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>
> 03-17 16:54:42.542: E/AndroidRuntime(1721):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)

Comment: What errors?  Do you expect us to guess?

Comment: no, of course not, but there are so many, I will edit it now and try to find a way it won't look like such a mess. sorry.

Edit: done. hope it will do good.

Comment: You have multiply inconsistent naming of your activity or activities.   In the Manifest you posted, you have an intent filter for an entity called `MainActivity`, but whatever apk you actually tried has a Manifest which causes the system to look for an activity called simply `Main` (from `Didn't find class "com.example.testapp.Main"`)  What is the name of your actual Activity java class file?

Comment: Basically, in my src folder I don't have an Activity java class. though by google, they said that should be a default one, so I dag up what I could from the internet thinking it was a generic use of activity in the manifest.

Comment: Jordan, help us help you by whittling down the amount of content you post. That list of errors is a touch loooooong.

Comment: I know, but due to the fact that I'm just a beginner I really don't know what to keep in there and what not. I will filter some though...

Comment: You seem to be trying to figure this out bit by bit; please consider downloading the SDK samples and looking at one of them such as "SkeletonActivity" in the "legacy" folder thereof.

Comment: Will do, thanks. I probably engaged from the wrong front.

I guess this topic could be locked.
I'd be happy to put it as an answer, if you comment in an answer :)